# How to Reverse a string with numbers, but don't reverse 1 and 0?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am learning random algorithms, and I am currently stock in one, where I have to reverse a string that contains numbers, but I am not to reverse 1 and 0 in the string e.g, 2345678910 would be 1098765432.

Here's what I've done so far:

```js
function split(str) {
  let temp = [];
  temp = str.split('');
  const backwards = [];
  const totalItems = str.length - 1;
  for (let i = totalItems; i >= 0; i--) {
    backwards.push(temp[i]);

  }
  return backwards.join('').toString();

}
console.log(split("10 2 3 U S A"));
console.log(split("2345678910"));
```

I am currently having the issue of not reversing the 10.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The result is `A S U 3 2 01` which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: OP wants `A S U 3 2 10` if I understood correctly

Comment: I added the other example mentioned above the snippet into it, as already two answers (mine deleted included) missed that one.

Comment: sorry @AxelJunes I voted to reject your edit, a bit too fast, because it would have cancelled mine done in the same time.

Comment: Are we assuming that `10` is always together and in that order?  If so, @OmG answer should be okay.

Comment: What about the string USA101001 ? Should it give 101001ASU ?

Comment: @Pac0 `U S A 10 10 0 1`→ `1 0 10 10 A S U` → `101010ASU`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl But OP said "not to reverse 1 and 0 in the string", which seems to imply that the whole sequence of 1 and 0s is not te be reversed.

Comment: I think the reversing rule is not clear. Normally 5864 would become 4685. But what 8150 should become? Certainly not 0518, but perhaps 5180 or 5810 or 1058 or else? This is not clear to me...:(

Comment: Do you mean, you would get correct result if you do it in two phases. Reverse everything in the string, then reverse every  `01` in place to get them back to being `10`?

Comment: So, is `[01]*` supposed to be treated as irreversible string, or is it just `10`?

Comment: This question is unclear. Does that mean the relative order between 0 and 1 should be maintained, or just the order of `10`?

Comment: The reversing order should not apply where there is a '10' together, as in ten in a given string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can replace `10` with a specified character which does not exist in the text, and after running the implemented algorithm replace it back with `10`.

```js
let out_of_alphabet_character = '#';
var reg_for_the_alphabet = new RegExp(out_of_alphabet_character, "g");

function specific_revert(str) {
  str = str.replace(/(10)/g, out_of_alphabet_character);
  let temp = [];
  
  temp = str.split('');
  const backwards = [];
  const totalItems = str.length - 1;
  for (let i = totalItems; i >= 0; i--) {
    backwards.push(temp[i]);
  }
  return backwards.join('').toString().replace(reg_for_the_alphabet, '10');
}
console.log(specific_revert("10 2 3 U S A"));
console.log(specific_revert("234567891010"));
```

Comment: That would be the simplest (in term of understandability) way of doing that IMHO

Comment: ha ! I think it fails for complex 10 strings like my example above : USA101001

Comment: @Pac0 What should be the result for `USA101001`?

Comment: We don't know yet, I presume. Need OP clarification. (but it works for both the examples given, at least)

Comment: This would work, but extend it so it replaces the longest sequence of `1` and `0` characters, not just `10`.

Comment: The reversing order should not apply where there is a '10' together, as in ten in a given string. so 01 does not apply.

Answer (score 4):

You can `reduce` over the matched array from using a regular expression. It's more costly than a for/loop that concatenates strings, but it was fun figuring it out.

```js
function split(str) {
  const re = /([A-Z23456789 ]+)|(10)/g
  return str.match(re).reduce((acc, c) => {

    // if the match is 10 prepend it to the accumulator
    // otherwise reverse the match and then prepend it
    acc.unshift(c === '10' ? c : [...c].reverse().join(''));
    return acc;      
  }, []).join('');
}

console.log(split('2345678910'));
console.log(split('10 2 3 U S A'));
console.log(split('2 3 U S A10'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just check for the special case & code the normal logic or reversing as usual

```js
    const reverse = str => {
     let rev = "";
     for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
         if (str[i] === '1' && i + 1 < str.length && str[i+1] === '0') {
             rev = '10' + rev;
                i++;
            } else rev = str[i] + rev;
        }
        
        return rev;
    }
    
    console.log(reverse("10 2 3 U S A")); // returns A S U 3 2 10
    console.log(reverse("2345678910")); // returns 1098765432
```

Comment: this code dose not work for  console.log(reverse("234567891000000")) only uses for 2345678910

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi I am getting "000001098765432", which seems to be the correct value.

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi No it is not... that was not a condition in the question.

Comment: OP said that he doesn't want to reverse 10, he doesn't say anything about how other values before or after 10 are affected. I don't know why would you even think that since its not even mentioned anywhere lol @mohammadjavadahmadi

Comment: @DanyalImran The examples from OP are only with '10', but OP said "not to reverse 1 and 0 in the string". But, of course, only OP himself can settle this requirement on those more involved examples.

Comment: @Pac0 definitely, we need more test cases for clarity.

Comment: tbf the title of the question refers to a string of numbers but the example the OP used had letters in too, so who knows what's up.

Answer (score 1):

You need some pre-conditions to check each character's value.

Due to the vagueness of the question, it is reasonable to believe that the number system that OP defines consists of [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and all other characters A-Z (including 0 and 1) are simply characters.

```js
String.prototype.isNumeric = function() {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(this)) && isFinite(this);
};

function reverse(str) {
  let tokens = [], len = str.length;
  while (len--) {
    let char = str.charAt(len);
    if (char.isNumeric()) {
      if (len > 0 && str.charAt(len - 1).isNumeric()) {
        let curr = parseInt(char, 10),
            next = parseInt(str.charAt(len - 1), 10);  
        if (curr === 0 && next === 1) {
          tokens.push(10);
          len--;
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
    tokens.push(char);
  }
  return tokens.join('');
}

console.log(reverse("10 2 3 U S A"));
console.log(reverse('2345678910'));
```

**Output:**

> ```
> A S U 3 2 10
> 1098765432
> ```

Comment: Based on the original example: "e.g, 2345678910 would be 1098765432."

Comment: my example is a bit complex, but OP gave at least an example with letters, 10 2 3 U S A

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.

Comment: this code dose not work for console.log(reverse("234567891000000")) only uses for 2345678910

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi That was not in the scope of the question.

Comment: i think it is a example.

Comment: It is not, and even if it was, this algorithm would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a recursive approach.

```js
function f(s, i=0){
  if (i == s.length)
    return '';
  if (['0', '1'].includes(s[i])){
    let curr = s[i];
    while (['0', '1'].includes(s[++i]))
      curr += s[i]
    return f(s, i) + curr;
  }
  return f(s, i + 1) + s[i];
}

console.log(f('10 2 3 U S A'));
console.log(f('2345678910'));
console.log(f('USA101001'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `USA101001` be `101010ASU` ?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I thought sequences of 1 and 0 were not to be reversed.

Comment: `U S A 10 10 0 1`→ `1 0 10 10 A S U` → `101010ASU`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl can you please show me where the OP indicated your interpretation is the correct one?

Comment: Due to the vagueness of the question, it is reasonable to believe that the number system is [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and all other characters A-Z (including 0 and 1) are simply characters.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl interesting idea. But OP didn't mention 10, rather 1 and 0.

Comment: It is assumed that, since 1 and 0 NEED to be together, it represents 10.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl OP didn't mention the word "together" either.

Comment: Well, they stated, _"I am currently having the issue of not reversing the 10"_. Also, why wasn't their example `A S U 3 2 1 0`?

Comment: I like this example, because I'm more inclined that the *whole* 1 and 0 string is to be preserved, even if it's unclear currently. At least that makes an answer covering this possiblity, it deserves its +1 as the others.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl ah, that's an interesting example. Let me think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question so far.

You may try this recursive approach(if not changing 10 for other character not allowed):

```js
function reverseKeepTen(str, arr = []) {
 const tenIdx = str.indexOf('10');
  
  if (!str.length) {
   return arr.join('');
  }
  
  if (tenIdx === -1) {
    return [...str.split('').reverse(), ...arr].join('');
  } else {
   const digitsBefore = str.slice(0, tenIdx);
    
   const arrBefore = digitsBefore ? [...digitsBefore.split(''), 10].reverse() : [10];
   return reverseKeepTen(str.slice(tenIdx + 2), [...arrBefore, ...arr])
  }
};


console.log(reverseKeepTen('101234105678910')) // 109876510432110
console.log(reverseKeepTen('12341056789')) // 98765104321
console.log(reverseKeepTen('1012345')) // 5432110
console.log(reverseKeepTen('5678910')) // 1098765
console.log(reverseKeepTen('10111101')) // 11011110
```